Why is it possible to refer to enum values when a field is named identically to the enum type, but not when the field type is made nullable?
Why does A work, but B fails to compile?
Is it a bug? If not, where this different behavior is described/specified?
enum ControlType { Foo }

class A
{
    public ControlType ControlType = ControlType.Foo;
}

class B
{
    public ControlType? ControlType = ControlType.Foo; // <-- error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'B.ControlType'
}


what version of c#? what tooling? that looks to be a bit of a bug, but your naming would be hard to follow

Side notes: (1) roslyn is not really material here - I get the same in vanilla VS. (2) Why would you want to use ControlType for a name of a field of that type (to me it's confusing, and changing the name of the field solves the problem) ?

The error is clear. The initializer can't reference the property ControlType. The compiler can't guess you meant to use the type name instead of the property name that's already in scope

@PanagiotisKanavos Why A compiles ok?

@DanielA.White Visual Studio 17.9.6. But same error is currently on main: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAExAagD4FMYFcwAIDCA9jAC4BOhANgCoCeADurgN64BihhuAvgLABQAgAIAmXAEEBzAblm4hAZgLFyVOo2WkKNBkwC8m1TsYA6DoQDcAvoP6jcAISky5iw9vXoA/O7W7cBkRafqbmVvzcQA

@wohlstad Roslyn is the C# compiler. It's very relevant, and indeed whether it repros in VS is immaterial. This is the "Color color" rule (google it), and this behaviour is well-specified

I'll answer that with a question. What's the type of B.ControlType ? It's Nullable<ControlType>, a reference type, not a value type like ControlType itself. You can't assing the integer value Foo to the reference type without a cast, which means it's a worse option for type inferencing. In A.ControlType the types are identical

@canton7 not really a bug, the types aren't the same.

@PanagiotisKanavos Nullable<T> is very much a value type, not a reference type. Conversions from Foo to Nullable<Foo> are well-specified

@canton7 I meant that because it reproduces on VS, it seems like it's a general issue in the C# language, and not a behavior of a specific compiler (Roslyn).

@wohlstad VS uses Roslyn to analyse and compile C# code

@canton7 even in a vanilla VS installation ? I was not aware of that. Good to know.

@canton7 oops, you're write. I was typing while experimenting in Sharplab. The fact remains, the two types are different, so the property takes precedence

@wohlstad compiler errors don't change when you change the editor. The compiler underneath is still the same

@wohlstad Yes. VS bundles the .NET SDK, which bundles Roslyn

@PanagiotisKanavos yes I am aware of that. But I thought that VS (VisualStudio, not VS code) comes with a MS compiler which is not related to Roslyn. I now understand that I was mistaken.

FWIW: https://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Binder_Expressions.cs,6348. Unfortunately that section number doesn't appear in the current spec. Trying to find it...

@canton7: My answer contains a link :)

@JonSkeet Aah, SO wasn't showing your answer! Thanks.

@wohlstad For a while it was true that VS continued to use the original c# compiler, while Roslyn was available and being built up.  From VS 2015 (I think), Roslyn was the new default.

@JamesThorpe thanks. I guass I was stuck in the past ;-)

@canton7 about the "Color Color" rule, I understand it is valid (and saw the link you posted under the answer). But I still personally find it clearer to use a slightly differnt name for the field.

@wohlstad Sure, but that doesn't change the fact that this behaviour is specified and should work. It's perfectly valid to ask questions about something, even if you personally wouldn't use it

@canton7 Maybe SO sometimes hides JonSheet's answers to delay reputation overflow :)

@canton7 I totally I agree. And BTW - this is why I started my original comment with "Side notes".

@TN. - Even if he excels, his name is Skeet, not Sheet. :-)

@OlivierJacot-Descombes That's true. But even if he excels here, his name is unfortunately not known to spellchecker.

The difference is whether the situation ends up meeting the requirements of section 12.8.7.2 of the C# spec - "Identical simple names and type names".

In a member access of the form E.I, if E is a single identifier, and if the meaning of E as a simple_name (§12.8.4) is a constant, field, property, local variable, or parameter with the same type as the meaning of E as a type_name (§7.8.1), then both possible meanings of E are permitted.  The member lookup of E.I is never ambiguous, since I shall necessarily be a member of the type E in both cases. In other words, the rule simply permits access to the static members and nested types of E where a compile-time error would otherwise have occurred.

In your case A, ControlType.Foo looks up ControlType, finds that it's a property with the same type as E (ControlType) and so allows the member lookup of Foo both as a static member of the type and as an member (via effectively accessing the ControlType property).
In your case B, ControlType.Foo looks up ControlType, finds that it's a property with a different type to E (it's ControlType? this time) so the member lookup proceeds only with the members of ControlType?.

Spec permalink

Your explanation is very logical, but why public ControlType? ControlType = Program.ControlType.Foo; works ? I would have expected something like (ControlType?)ControlType.Foo; to works, but no...

@gobes: because in that case the member lookup of ControlType is performed on Program, which resolves to a namespace, so Program.ControlType resolves to the enum (not the property), and Program.ControlType.Foo just resolves to the value. There's then an implicit conversion from Program.ControlType to Nullable<Program.ControlType>. I'm not sure why you wouldn't have expected it to work.

Ah, I get it now... some days are harder than others...
